# Build remote multibranch pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to use the parameterized remote trigger plugin to run the remote project(all branches) and monitor only one of the branches for the status.

```
node(''){
 triggerRemoteJob abortTriggeredJob: true, auth: CredentialsAuth(credentials: 'E2E'), job: 'http://localhost:8080/job/test-projectF', maxConn: 5, useCrumbCache: true, useJobInfoCache: true
}
```

This is my code to trigger the remote project. But I end up with an exception

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] triggerRemoteJob################################################################################################################
Parameterized Remote Trigger Configuration:
- job:                     http://localhost:8080/job/test-projectF 
- auth:                    'Credentials Authentication' as user 'admin' (Credentials ID 'E2E')
- parameters:              
- blockBuildUntilComplete: true
- connectionRetryLimit:    5

 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // node
 [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["property"] is not a JSONArray.
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:1986)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.isRemoteJobParameterized(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:1086)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.performTriggerAndGetQueueId(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:637)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.pipeline.RemoteBuildPipelineStep$Execution.run(RemoteBuildPipelineStep.java:263)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.pipeline.RemoteBuildPipelineStep$Execution.run(RemoteBuildPipelineStep.java:239)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:51)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:48)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

However, same command with a branch name ends in SUCCESS. `http://localhost:8080/job/test-projectF/job/master`

What is the better way to build the dynamically created branch on the remote Jenkins and track the status?